# HAC standard errors in a VAR in statsmodels?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to get HAC standard errors when using the `VAR` class in `statsmodels`. I know that I can estimate the `VAR` equation by equation like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9,1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,2,5,7,1,9,5,3,2,5,4,3,6,4,1,1,9]})

df['La'] = df.a.shift(1)
df['Lb'] = df.b.shift(1)
df['L2a'] = df.a.shift(2)
df['L2b'] = df.b.shift(2)

reg = smf.ols('a ~ 1 + La+ Lb +L2a + L2b',data=df).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':2})
```

However, I am unable specify the `cov_type` when using `VAR`. What is the issue here?

```
regvar = VAR(df[['a','b']]).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':2})
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hedi\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17856/2799803864.py", line 1, in <module>
    regvar = VAR(df[['a','b']]).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':2})

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cov_type'
```

Comment: There do not seem to be any way to specify the cov_type when using VAR, see docs: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.fit